# Validar checkbox en un modal obligatoria mente para acceder al sitio web

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una pagina web, que al ingresar muestra un modal que requiere que se validen unos checkbox obligatorios para poder acceder al sitio, ¿como podría hacer para que solo deje salir del modal e ingresar al sitio cuando todos los checkbox estén validados?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar JQuery para hacer tu validación

```
var cnt=$("input").length;
var checados=$("input:checked").length;
if(cnt<checados){
    alert("Incompletos");
}
```